# Redirect non existing page to frontpage

Tags: redirect, urls

When a user type inn www.mypage.com/x (which does not exist) the result show an empty body with the header and the footer intact. Most redirect plugins let me redirect one specific URL to another specific URL. What i want is to not only redirect a specific URL, but every non existing URL to a specific URL.

What does this redirecting action called, and how to i do that?

Comment: Do you mean redirect on 404 not found?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [conditional tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) `is_404()` and `wp` action hook to redirect whenever the page can not be found.

*functions.php*

```
add_action( 'wp', 'se344018_redirect_404' );
function se344018_redirect_404()
{
    if ( is_404() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        //
        // wp_redirect( home_url('some/page-slug') );
        exit;
    }
}
```